How to apply translate one more time to a target that has already been translate
#cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.1s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#moon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(186, 186, 186);
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(80px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(80px);
  }
}

First of all, I'm really sorry that there might be an error in the question using the translator.

I'd like to rotate 'moon' around 'cursor'.
'cursor' has 'translate (-50%, -50%); and 'moon' has also tried to apply this but failed.
I think that's because 'translateX' has already been applied.
Is there a way to apply 'translate (-50%, -50%) to a target that already has 'translateX'?
I've been searching for a couple of hours for a way to fix this, but I couldn't find it. (This is probably because I didn't search correctly, but I did my best.)
I've tried everything I can to get it done, but it hasn't had much of an effect.
Please help. This is my first question, so please let me know if there's anything that goes against the rules.
Thank you

First of all, please present a [mre] of your issue, when asking this kind of question, and not just snippets that lack context.

transform is one CSS property, so you can not define it in multiple places and hope the transformations would "add up" somehow. You need to either integrate this translate offset into the value you are specifying inside your keyframe (using calc() to get the combination of -50% and 80px for X right), or use an additional wrapper element in your HTML, so that you can apply transform two times, once on the outer and once on the inner element.
